# What do I say when a friend tells me about the death of a loved one?

Tags: word-choice

I never know what to say/write in Chinese when a friend tells me that one of their relatives or friends has passed away. I'm aware of the terms of politeness for referring to the death itself:

- [Politeness in referring to a recent death](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17175/politeness-in-referring-to-a-recent-death)
- [What is the polite way to say a grandparent has passed away?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21515/what-is-the-polite-way-to-say-a-grandparent-has-passed-away)

But I don't know what to say to the person who has just told me that someone they know just died. It is hard enough in English to know what to say, but I might say something like "Oh, I'm really sorry to hear that." or "I'm sorry for your loss." What can I say in Chinese that will be comforting, culturally appropriate, and won't sound trite?

I'd like to know for both the situation of a very close friend/relative dying and also for a more distant friend/relative dying. I assume one might say different things depending on how close they were.

Recent example of a more distant relative passing away:

- **Friend:** "我们去【某地方】参加我四舅的葬礼去了，明天晚上十点左右才回来。谅！" *(We had originally planned to meet the next day.)*
- **Me:** ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are notified a distant relative of someone has just passed away, you don't need to say much, just a simple "這樣啊" (Oh, I see) and/or "那真不幸" (that's really unfortunate) to acknowledge you have just learned the bad news.

If you are notified a close relative of someone has just passed away, you should add an condolences, and the most common phrase for offering condolences is **節哀順變** or **節哀**

- "這樣啊... 那真不幸，希望你能[節哀順變](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/54388/)" (Oh, I see... That's really unfortunate, hope you can restrain your grief and accept the change)
- "這樣啊... 那真不幸，請[節哀](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/49231/) (Oh, I see... That's really unfortunate, please restrain your grief)

Answer (score 0):

Besides what Tang Ho has provided. In a real practice (informal circumstances), if one's close friend/relative passed away, you could say these sentences: "真的啊！/真的吗! 什么时候的事情啊？ 那现在怎么样了？ 太不幸了！有什么我可以帮忙的吗？" If you feel your friend really sad, you could say: "你也别太难过了！ 人死不能复生。" You could apply those sentences according to the situations. These are all colloquial sentences.

Comment: *"人死不能复生"* - Are you sure this wouldn't be offensive?

Comment: "人死不能复生". It's often used. You would hear it from TV shows sometimes. It's not offensive.